# Parameter from button to modal and then call Spring controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'm enough new with html/javascript so I would need an advice. I have to call modal from button and in this modal I would like to see a table obtained from database.
So my idea is to call modal through button so:

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="fleet : ${fleets}">
    <td th:text="${fleet.application}"></td>
    <td th:text="${fleet.cubic}"></td>
    <td th:text="${fleet.power}"></td>
    <td th:text="${fleet.euroClass}"></td>
    <td th:text="${fleet.engineType}"></td>
    <td th:text="${fleet.traction}"></td>
    <td th:text="${fleet.transmission}"></td>
    <td><button data-id="showCarsButton" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#modalShowCar">Show cars</button></td>
    <td><button id="addCarButton" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary">Add car</button></td>
</tr>
```

temporary modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalShowCar" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Fleet cars</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

temporary js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modalShowCar').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var idFleet = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "cars/"+ idFleet,
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success : function(data) {
                if (data.status==200){
                    //I have to pass to modal the data.body
                } else {
                    //show error
                }
            },
            error : function(data) {
                window.location.href = "/500"; //Redirect to page 500
            }
        });
     });
});
```

and then from modal call the Spring controller with data-url into table tag.
I need to pass parameter (id) to perform the query, so from the button to the url into modal, how can I do it? Is this the best way?
thanks,regards

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you are trying, with your appraoch, you can use [bootstrap modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) and pass the id to modal

change `id="showCarsButton"` to `data-id="showCarsButton"`

```
<button data-id="showCarsButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShowCar">Show cars</button></td>
```

JS

```
$('#modalShowCar').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var carid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
   // Do Whatever you like to do,
 });
```

Example Code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#modalShowCar').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var carid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        alert(carid);
        $(".modal-body").html(carid);
       // Do Whatever you like to do,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShowCar" data-id="showCarsButton">Open Modal</button>
<div id="modalShowCar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is better than onclick inside the button tag?To pass the list to modal after ajax call?

Comment: onclick may not give you desired result

Comment: I have to pass ${fleet.idFleet} for the future query. In ajax I can call controller, it returns a List that I have to show into modal. I have a problem to pass fleet.idFleet and the List to modal

Comment: I'm trying, but the button does'nt call the modal

Comment: if you copied the code from answer, there is a typo mistake `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">` modal id change it to `"#modalShowCar"` and also you have to make the similar changes in JS code

Comment: this is wrong `var carid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('showCarsButton');` look at the code in answer

Comment: I resolved the problem was the bootstrap javascript, now I try with variable

Comment: sure, lemme know if you face any issue

Comment: the param th:attr="data-id=${fleet.idFleet}" works, now in my javascript, after ajax restful call, how can I pass my List<Car> to modal and use it with thymeleaf ?

Comment: can you update the question with the code, Ajax call and how you are trying to pass the list?

Comment: I updated with ajax code, I don't have idea to how pass the list, I have ever used the spring controller

Comment: `if (data.status==200){$(".modal-body").html(data)}`

Comment: if (data.status==200){$(".modal-body").html(data.body)} but in html table how can I read it with thymeleaf?